# Validate XML and XSD in Eclipse 4.2 - missing option?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I switched to Eclipse 4.2 a while back and everything is perfect, but now I noticed when I right click an XML or XSD file, I don't have the option to validate that file anymore (3.7 worked fine).

Can I add these features through some plugin? Or is the option just hidden in some sub menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What package of 4.2 did you download? I think that feature is only available in some of the packages, such as **IDE for Java EE Developers** and **IDE for Java Developers**.

*Hint: you can see what features are included in each package by clicking the `Details` link next to the package on the downloads page.*